# How do I write to a Mysql database in VB.net with a query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, forms, basic

I am trying to make a little program that writes and reads from a Mysql database. The reading part is going well, but I am a bit stuck in the write part.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Absenden.Click
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim myConnectionString As String
    myConnectionString = "server=Nothing;uid=to;pwd=see;database=here;"
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim Querywrite As String
        Querywrite = "select * FROM here.message INSERT INTO message admin='" & TB_Name.Text & "' and message='" & TB_Nachricht.Text & "' and Server='" & TB_Server.Text & "' and status='" & TB_Status.Text & "' "
        command = New MySqlCommand(Querywrite, connection)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

The `Querywrite` part is the problem I think. The input comes from Textboxes in a Windows Form.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your SELECT ... INSERT syntax is invalid. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Beside you need to read about Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection(s)..  https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Iam trying to insert the Inputs of the Textboxes in the Database.

Comment: [SQL INSERT INTO Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: I've this Site open to, but I am maybe a bit to stupid to figure it out.

Comment: Not a huge fan of the w3 site but this is the page you want: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, if someone shows you once then you will get the idea. The main thing is to always use parameters; not only will you avoid minor sytax and type errors but you will avoid major disasters of malicious input. I guessed at the datatypes of your fields. Please check your database for the types and adjust your code accordingly.

```
Private Sub InsertData()
        Dim strQuery As String = "Insert Into message (admin, message, Server, status) Values (@admin, @message, @Server, @status);"     
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("your connection string")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand With {
                    .Connection = cn,
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    .CommandText = strQuery}
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@admin", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = TB_Name.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@message", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = TB_Nachricht.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Server", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = TB_Server.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = TB_Status.Text
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thx a ton. Except from the @statue in the frist line ;). Thx again for the help.

Comment: @thunfischbaum Oops! So sorry, fixed it.